# pegar valor de uma variável JS e colocar em um input value

Tags: javascript

estou querendo pegar um valor de uma variável javascript e colocar dentro de um `input` value pra enviar via `get`.

Meu JS esta assim:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var count = 10;

  $('a[name=alex]').click(function() {
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "" + count + "";
    count += 10;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contador">
  <div class="cont_sub0">
    <h4>Pontuação</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="cont_sub1"><span id="resultado">000</span>
  </div>

  <input type="text" value="resultado" id="resultado">

</div>
```

Não estou conseguindo colocar o resultado no value, esta mostrando perfeito, mas, no `input` não pega.

Answer (score 2):

A propriedade `innerHTML` serve pra escrever ou retornar o conteúdo de um elemento HTML, no caso o atributo que queres mudar é o `value`

```
document.getElementById("resultado").value = count;
```

Veja funcionando

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var count = 10;

  $('a[name=alex]').click(function() {
    document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "" + count + "";
    document.getElementById("input").value = count;
    count += 10;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contador">
  <div class="cont_sub0">
    <h4>Pontuação</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="cont_sub1"><span id="span" name="resultado">000</span>
  </div>

  <input type="text" value="resultado" id="input" name="resultado">
  <a name="alex" href="#">teste</a>
</div>
```

---

Outros adendos:

- O atributo `id` é vinculado a apenas um elemento em cada pagina `html`;
- Se por acaso quiser trabalhar do mesmo modo com elementos que sejam do mesmo tipo, deve usar `document.getElementsByName("name_do_elemento")` ou ainda `document.getElementsByClassName("name_da_class")` que são meios mais genéricos de pegar múltiplos elementos que possuam mesmo nome ou mesma classe, respectivamente;
- Deves ainda levar em conta que cada elemento se trabalha de uma forma, `inputs` do tipo texto se altera o valor para se obter o resultado esperado, e não o conteúdo, já elementos do tipo `div`, ou `span`, se altera o conteúdo, por exemplo.